# Bind state to conditional statement inside of map function in React

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I have a list of posts where clicking one will toggle the post and show its comments. I want the comments to load and show up conditionally based on whether or not the post is toggled, but I can't access state in my method checking if the post is toggled or not.

Isn't the context supposed to be bound automatically with arrow functions?

```
var PostList = React.createClass({ 
  componentDidMount() {
    this.state = {};     
    const posts = this.props.posts;      
    posts.forEach(function(post) {         
      this.state[post._id] = false;
    });        
  },

  isToggled(post) {                
    return this.state[post];      
  },

  render: function() {
    var postList = posts.map((post,index) => (
    <div class=“post”>
      {post.content}<br/>     
      {this.isToggled(post._id) ?       
      <Comments postId={post._id}/>     
      :''}
    </div>
  ))
 }
```

Result:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'idyadayada' of null
```

Comment: You're not using arrow functions with the `forEach` in `componentDidMount` and remember you can't assign directly to `state`. You gotta go through `setState`.

Comment: You are right but state is being set correctly and my click handlers (only posted parts of the class) with 'this' bound explicitly are working fine (onClick={this.togglePost.bind(this, post._id)} for example).

Answer (score 0):

```
USe this.setState outside the forEach




getInitialState(){
  return {
  }
}
       componentDidMount() {
            this.state = {};                 
            const posts = this.props.posts;           
            var newState = {} ;      
            posts.forEach(function(post) {                     
              newState[post._id] = false;
            });              
            this.setState({
              state: newState
            }      
          },
```

Comment: Still not working.. I posted condensed code, I know from other functions in the class that are called with this explicitly bound that state is set correctly. I.e. for example onClick={this.togglePost.bind(this, post._id)} is working properly.

Comment: add getInitial state to your component